# GnuPlot: Data Format for Heat Map?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to do a heat map in GnuPlot.  Here's the data:

[image]

I got it working with this data layout:

[image]

...but I had to round the Y Axis values to the nearest 5 to get them to fit in the exact rows of the grid.

So I'm trying to figure out a more 3D data layout. I tried something like this:

```
X    Y    Z
1   69  3.9

2   44  5.2

3   39  2.6

4   51  5.1

5   50  2.2

6   47  2.5

7   52  2.1

8   52  2.6

9   52  4.0
```

...but I got a "Singular matrix in LU-DECOMP" error.

I tried doing multiple rows in the data file for each value of Z, but I couldn't figure out what to put for the empty X and Y positions.

What's the correct way to lay out a data file like this?

For completeness, here's my command file:

```
unset surface
unset key
set view map
set pm3d
set palette defined (0 'black', 1 'gray40', 2 'dark-green', 3 '#fee000', 4 '#fc7a00', 5 '#ff0000')
set cbrange [0:5]
set output 'temp.jpg'

set term jpeg size 900, 900 enhanced font '/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf' 12  #000000 Effffff
set dgrid3d 400,400 splines
set size square
set xtics("" 1, "X Label 1" 2, "X Label 2" 3, "X Label 3" 4, "X Label 4" 5, "X Label 5" 6, "X Label 6" 7, "X Label 7" 8, "X Label 8" 9, "X Label 9" 10)
unset label
unset title
set title '{/=18 Title}'  offset 0, .5
set ylabel '{/=18 Y Label}'  offset -1.6, 0
set xlabel '{/=18 X Label}'  offset 0,-3.0
set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror
set ytics("25" 0, "30" 1, "35" 2, "40" 3, "45" 4, "50" 5, "55" 6, "60" 7, "65" 8, "70" 9, "75" 10, "" 11)
set y2tics("25" 0, "30" 1, "35" 2, "40" 3, "45" 4, "50" 5, "55" 6, "60" 7, "65" 8, "70" 9, "75" 10, "" 11)

set xrange [0:11] 
set yrange [0:11]
unset colorbox 

set link x2; set link y2

splot [1:] '/gnuplot_data_test_v400.txt' matrix

replot


# http://hirophysics.com/gnuplot/gnuplot10.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154364/gnuplot-pm3d-plot-triangle-data?rq=1
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/900501/i-cant-splot-with-pm3d-map-my-data-file-gnuplot
# http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile-e.html#3dim
# http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_3d.htm
```

**Update:** Here's the kind of chart I'm trying to make:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what your exact expectations are..., but I would use the plotting style `with boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`).

**Code:**

```
### heatmap with boxxyerror
reset session

# X    Y    Z
$Data <<EOD
1   69  3.9
2   44  5.2
3   39  2.6
4   51  5.1
5   50  2.2
6   47  2.5
7   52  2.1
8   52  2.6
9   52  4.0
EOD

myXLabels = '"Label A" "Label B" "Label C" "Label D" "Label E" "Label F" "Label G" "Label H" "Label I"'
myXtic(col) = word(myXLabels,int(column(col)))
BoxWidth = 1
BoxHeight = 1
xLow(col)  = column(col)-BoxWidth/2.
xHigh(col) = column(col)+BoxWidth/2.
yLow(col)  = column(col)-BoxHeight/2.
yHigh(col) = column(col)+BoxHeight/2.

set style fill solid 1.0
plot $Data u 1:2:(xLow(1)):(xHigh(1)):(yLow(2)):(yHigh(2)):3:xtic(myXtic(1)) w boxxy fc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Without knowing the details of your application, the following might be a starting point. Add some points in the corners with z=0. And you might want to "play" with the values in the line `set dgrid3d 200,200 gauss kdensity 1.5`.

**Code:**

```
### heatmap with interpolation
reset session

# X    Y    Z
$Data <<EOD
1   69  3.9
2   44  5.2
3   39  2.6
4   51  5.1
5   50  2.2
6   47  2.5
7   52  2.1
8   52  2.6
9   52  4.0
EOD

# add some points in the corners with z=0
set print $Data append
do for [x=0:10:10] {
    do for [y=35:70:35] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g",x,y,0)
    }
}
set print

set view map
set palette defined (0 'black', 1 'gray40', 2 'dark-green', 3 '#fee000', 4 '#fc7a00', 5 '#ff0000')
set dgrid3d 200,200 gauss kdensity 1.5
unset key
set tics out

splot $Data u 1:2:3 w pm3d
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this advice, @theozh. I've updated the original post with an example of the kind of chart I'm trying to create. Is there a way to create that chart with the data format you've provided?

Comment: @VikR see modified answer. Does this answer your question? However, I would be careful with interpolations. In some cases it might give the impression like there is some data although it's probably just an interpolation artefact, e.g. the vertical grey "line" in the plot in your question.